# What is the Oracle PL/SQL equivalent of this method?

Tags: html, oracle, plsql, escaping, apache-commons

I am building an SQL query that will find some text to be displayed in a web browser.

```
SELECT
   description
FROM
   my_table
WHERE
   <condition_here>
```

The description can contain some characters that need to be html escaped.

If I was in Java I would use [StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html#escapeHtml4%28java.lang.String%29).

Due to custom security policy, I can't load the Apache Commons jar in the Oracle 10g database. So I have to use a function available in Oracle PL/SQL. `UTL_URL.ESCAPE` is for URL. `HTF.ESCAPE_SC` seems to manage only a few cases not like `StringEscapeUtils#escapeHtml4`...

What Oracle PL/SQL function/procedure can I use ?

**Oracle 10gR2**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best shot probably be write your own escapeHTML4 function in PLSQL. Translate all these characters: [BASIC, ISO8859_1, HTML40_EXTENDED](http://grepcode.com/file_/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3/3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/text/translate/EntityArrays.java/?v=source)

This is what escapeHTML4 in Java does

Do something like: `SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(html, '&', '&amp;') FROM A;`